# Apple Review: This item is no longer available [Environment Sandbox]

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, sandbox, appstore-approval

I have implemented an In-App purchase in my IOS App. It is working well on my Sandbox accounts which I have added in the Testers List. But when I submitted my App for Apple review. They rejected my App with the following error and screenshot.

**Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness**

We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 13.3.1 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, your app displayed an error message “This item is no longer available“ upon finalizing in-app purchase.

[image]

As I described above its working well with my Sandbox testing accounts. Like in-app products are created with same identifiers. So then what could be the possible issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I currently have the same issue with my app. Although I did not submit the app to review, when purchasing using a sandbox account, I get this error message. It was working well yesterday... Can you check if it is still working using your sandbox testing account right now? My guess is that it's an issue with the iTunes sandbox that they will have to fix...

Comment: Thanks for the information, yes i will check again by creating another sandbox account, and let you know.

Comment: There have been some widespread issues with sandbox for the past week or so... Unfortunately Apple is rejecting apps for their own bug.

Comment: I’ve been having the same issue. Every time I test my non-consumable iAP in the sandbox, it works fine. If it’s apple’s fault and not mine, it’s pretty aggravating that I’ve gotten rejected twice for this issue.

Comment: thanks for the information, but @AidanKaiser how did you succeed to resolve the problem then?

Comment: I have submitted an appeal to Apple, lets see what happens.

Comment: Let me know what happens please! I haven’t been able to get it resolved. My (temporary) solution is submitting my app for review with no in app purchases. If your appeal succeeds, I will definitely follow suit.

Comment: In Appeal, they have approved my in-App purchases and also approved my App. It's done now. In that appeal, I have also mentioned the reference to this post and told many guys have been facing this same issue. So, it was right the issue was on Apple's side which they have hopefully fixed now. You can try by submitting your Apps as well :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a compliance question for Apple Support. it's not a programming question.